# Stop the refreshing of a page when i press the submit button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Actually I have this code:

```
<input type='submit' name='bn_search' value='<?php echo xla('Search'); ?>'/>
  .....
<?php if ($_REQUEST['bn_search']) { ?>  
<?php ....... } ?>
```

I have created a submit button "Search" and when I press this button the page will refresh and I want to prevent it. The button,also, shows some results from the database.Can I make it working without refreshing? If anyone can help me I would appreciate it.

Comment: You're looking for [Ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: What you mean? can you give me any example please?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("form").on('submit', function(e){

    e.preventDefault()

});
```

Edited due to tip in comments @carpetsmoker

Comment: Use `e.preventDefault()`. this is actually a lot better, since it's executed on the first line, meaning. If your function contains an error (exception), then `return false` is never reached and strange (unexpected) behaviour can ensue. `return false` is really an old hack from the early days of Javascript.

Comment: Ok cheers for the tip

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work ..